# Fancybox opens in test page, not in actual page

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox, rgba

Fancybox 2.0 is launching exactly as I want it to in my test page.  However, it isn't opening in my actual page.

My test page is at http://beta.nathanbunn.co.uk/js/fancybox/test.html and my actual page is http://beta.nathanbunn.co.uk/portfolio/actonco2/.  For the actual page, there is a text link that says "Link" that should fire up Fancybox, but it opens the link as a standard link and not in FB.  Since I know Fancybox 2.0 is generally discussed here as opposed to the original Google Groups forum, I have posted this message in both forums, but I really need assistance on this.  I know it is a problem with my main page and not Fancybox itself (the test page works fine enough), so any assistance would be fantastic.

Also, if anyone can help, I have tried in Chrome and Firefox and the black background is always black, no matter what colour I set it to, even in the Fancybox script.  What could I have done wrong there?  I want it to be white and the rgbA values don't seem to be accepted.

Comment: I do also know that my code is a mess.  My Fancybox controls are on lines 9, 11, 14 and 218-226, with my firing link on line 168.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this js error in your "actual" page:

Error: $clicked.parents().hasClass("dtMenu").hasID is not a function
Source File: http://beta.nathanbunn.co.uk/portfolio/actonco2/
Line: 75

from this line of code

```
if (! $clicked.parents().hasClass("dtMenu").hasID("networkDT"))
```

that breaks all your js code so fancybox will never work.

BTW, I didn't know that jQuery already has the "hasID" method ?!?!?!

you should rather use [javascript's getElementById method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp)

Comment: That seems to work!  Thanks!  Now I am left with the background colour ... it only seems to be so in Chrome and Firefox ... K-Meleon seems to work fine :S

Answer (score 1):

Your Fancybox dows not show up because you don't include the JavaScript ;-)

Your link in your documents header points to nowhere

http://beta.nathanbunn.co.uk/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js

results in **Error 404 Not Found**

Comment: Modified that ... I forgot that I included the file in a subfolder :$  That being said, it still doesn't seem to fire, but I'm sure there is another simple thing I have forgotten ...